# .net api controller return two response in swagger

Tags: .net, api, swagger

I have one problem with my project. I have one service for calling external API which returns some data. It returns data correctly. But the problem is in my API controller with Swagger. When I click on API in swagger doc even without clicking "Try to execute" I get a Response in form of my model but with empty values. When I click on Execute I get the correct response on swagger, and below this correct response is one that I got before this correctly.
I guess that is because of return values but I can't figure out what is problem...

My service

```
public async Task<EmployeeDetails> EmployeeDetails(int employeId)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "bearertokenvalue");
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://someapi/employee/{employeId}");
            var resultData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            EmployeeDetails employe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeDetails>(resultData.Result);
            return employe;
        }
```

Api controller

```
    [HttpGet]
        public async Task<EmployeeDetails> Run()
        {
            var response = await _employeService.EmployeeDetails(2);
            return response;
        }
```

Comment: Before executing the API, Swagger shows the empty model in the responses tab and it is the default behaviour.

Comment: You want to say this is normal behaviour ? But how how is possible that is only on this action swagger return empy response and correct response, but not on others ?

Comment: Does your API returns correct response after executing it on Swagger?

Comment: Ofcourse, I mention that in my post. When I execute response, it returns correct response. Problem is only because I dont like this "example response".

Comment: This is the default behavior, because of your return type "EmployeeDetails" for other actions what is your return type. if  it a defined structure/model then it will show for others also. if you don't like empty value then you can provide example value so that it will be shown.